# Move every 15th Column to a New Row

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet but all the data came in on Row 1. I need to move every 16th Column to the next row. So my data is supposed to be in Columns 1 thru Column 15. I'm not very Excel savvy so please bear with me.

Comment: How did the data get into Excel? It may be easier to import in a different way than manipulate it from the current form it is in.

Comment: It came in as a CSV File and normally I would do the comma delimited and divide them out by commas but it's puts all of them in Row 1. 

If I copy row 1 from Excel and paste it into Word, it doesn't format correctly to the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub dividde_16()

No_of_columns = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
No_of_rows = Int(No_of_columns / 15) + 1

For i = 1 To No_of_rows
 For j = 1 To 15
  Cells(i + 1, j) = Cells(i * 15 + j)
Next
Next
Range(Cells(1, 16), Cells(1, No_of_columns)) = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this:

```
Sub Move_to_Columns()
Dim lR As Long, R As Range
lR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set R = Range("A1", "A" & lR)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For Each C In R
    If C.Row Mod 16 = 0 Then
        C.Offset(-1, 1).Value = C.Value
        C.ClearContents
    End If
Next C
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

But with columns instead of rows.